# Emberjs Input TextField value Unicode convert

Tags: javascript, unicode, ember.js

I Need to convert input values into unicode values by using some function in the onKeyPress and onKeyDown event.

How do I create the view in Ember.js for the TextField?

Ex: in Javascript

```
<input name="comment" charset="utf-8" type="text" onKeyPress="javascript:convertThis(event)" onKeyDown="toggleKBMode(event)" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to create your own input text is extending the `Ember.TextField`

```
App.MyTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    attributeBindings: ['charset'],
    charset: 'utf-8',
    keyPress: function(evt) {
        console.log('keyPress', evt);
    },
    keyDown: function(evt) {        
        console.log('keyDown', evt);
    }
});
```

`attributeBindings` will say what is the properties of your `App.MyTextField` to be used like html attributes, in your case the charset: `attributeBindings: ['charset']`. And to get the `keyPress` and `keyDown` events just declare your respective functions. It will receive a [jQuery.Event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) instance.

This is a fiddle with this sample http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/cEAhN/

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much [marcio-rodrigues-correa-junior](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1846480/marcio-rodrigues-correa-junior) :)